# how i can test the connectionstring in Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection-string

I have a connectionstring in Mysql and how i can check that is valid or not means to say  i want to test the connectionstring as well other software give functionality like in many software a option come called something like `Test Connection` [based on connectionstring].

any c# sample code to do that

Comment: are you looking for all ODBC connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a connection read server version or some generic data which you know for sure, would be present on database server. For example I read `@@version` in SQL Server to check what version of SQL Server user has and show the version. If no version returned connection couldn't be established.

Comment: then you are not really "**Testing the Connection**", are you? I thought that was the purpose of this question.

Comment: I thing to get the error something like your username is invalid or you need to use pass something like error that. how i can get them.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are asking about, and again I dont know about `mysql`, check the `mysql` documentation to get any authentication errors.